# Какие есть способы поиска элемента во вложенных массивах?

Tags: php

Задан массив такого формата:

```
$arr = [
  ['cost' => 100, 'age' => 50],
  ['cost' => 34, 'age' => 150],
  ['cost' => 56, 'age' => 99],
];
```

Хотел бы узнать, какие есть способы поиска элемента с максимальным (или минимальным) `cost`.
Например, банальное решение в лоб - это итеративный поиск, через цикл.

Как это можно через array_reduce решить, или другие функции ?

Comment: Еще вариант с сортировкой, но это не лучшее решение, т.к. в данной задаче O(n) это максимум, что требуется)

Comment: а array_reduce  - это не цикл?

Comment: написано про вложенные массивы, но тут, если округлить, одномерность

Comment: `array_reduce` ровным счетом то же самое, только данные о значении и индексе макс/мин элемента вы храните не в переменных, а в возвращаемом значении